# How am I supposed to add a JSP file to my application?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, vaadin

I have created a new JSP file called loggedOut.jsp and after I click logout in my app I want to be directed to it. Instead of going to the loggedOut.jsp file though I am brought to the login page but the url shows as going to loggedOut.jsp.

I'm using tomcat 7 and vaadin.

How do I get my app to take me to the loggedOut.jsp?

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Messages</display-name>
<context-param>
    <description>
    Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</p+aram-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MessagesApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.vaadin.artur.icepush.ICEPushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>
        Vaadin application class to start</description>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.entropix.msgapp.main.MsgApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>
        Application widgetset</description>
        <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
        <param-value>com.entropix.msgapp.main.widgetset.MessagesWidgetset</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginFailed.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loggedOut.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MessagesApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>LoginConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MessagesUser</web-resource-name>
        <description>Messages Application Authenticated User</description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>messages-user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <description>Messages User</description>
    <role-name>messages-user</role-name>
</security-role>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginFailed.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Comment: For getting better help, please post whatever you have done till now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably configured the webapp (or a filter in the webapp) to redirect to the login page for all (or a whole lot) of "protected" URLs, if the user is not authenticated.

Make sure the loggedOut.jsp is not part of those "protected" URLs (or url patterns) that need to be authenticated to be accessed. This is normally configured in the web.xml file, but you're the only one to know how your app works.

EDIT: now you've shown us the web.xml file, look inside it. You're defining a resource collection with the url pattern `/*` (which means every URL of the webapp) which needs to be in the role `messages-user` to be accessed. This means that to access every URL of the webapp, you must be authenticated and have gained the messages-user role through this authentication. So, as soon as you log out, you redirect the user to logedOut.jsp. But since the URL needs to be authenticated to be accessed, the login page is displayed.

Here is a tutorial for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncas.html

Comment: Where would I find the "protected" urls?

Comment: As I said: "This is normally configured in the web.xml file".

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. I'm very new to this and am not sure what to be looking for as far as finding these protected urls.  I added this to my web.xml just like i already have for login.jsp. I don't see anywhere else that would not allow me to navigate to it.

servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/loggedOut.jsp</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: This addition to web.xml is not needed. It's just unnecessary noise. Why don't you edit your question and show us the web.xml file? And since you're dealing with authentication in a JEE webapp, why don't you read the specification, or at least tutorials, that talk about it? Trying random solutions is not the best strategy.

Comment: I've been trying to find some tutorials on doing this but have been unsuccessful. I posted my web.xml as it is right now.